# WebSphere propagating changes to customized cache across all servers in a cluster

Tags: java, jms, websphere, distributed-caching

Food We are using WAS 7.0, with a customized local cache in a clustered environment.  In our application there is some very commonly used (and very seldomly updated) reference information that is retrieved from the database and stored in a customized cache on server start up (We do not use the cache thru the application server).  New Reference values can be entered through the application, when this is done, the data in the database is updated and the cached data on that single server (1 of 3) is reflected. If a user hits any of the other servers in that cluster they will not see the newly entered reference values (unless the server is bounced). Restarting the cluster is not a feasible solution as it will bring down production.  My question is how do I tell the other servers to update their local cache as well?

I looked at JMS publish/subscribe mechanism. I was thinking of publishing a message every time I update values of any reference table, and the other servers can act as subscribers and get the message and refresh their cache. The servers need to act as both a publisher and a subscriber.  I am not sure how to incorporate this solution to my application. I am open to suggestions and other solutions as well.

Answer (score 0):

In general you should consider Dynamic cache service provided by application server. It has already replication options out of the box. Check [Using the DistributedMap and DistributedObjectCache interfaces for the dynamic cache](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tdyn_distmap.html?lang=en) for more details.

And regarding your custom JMS solution - you should have MDB in your application, which will be configured to the topic. Once cache is changed, your application will publish change to that topic. MDB reads that message and updates the local cache.

But since it is quite complex change, I'd strongly consider switching to the built in cache.